# How to delete group of folders based on name and date

Tags: centos, shell-script

I have a folder structure like this.

```
folders
    test1
    test2.1
    test49.85
    test4.95.89
    sample
    support
    util
```

These are all folders. I need to delete all folders that begin with test, except the most recent one. I do have access to the folder name of the most recent ${newestTestFolder} also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `extglob` in Bash:

```
$ ls -1
sample
support
test1
test2.1
test4.95.89
test49.85
util
$ newestTestFolder="test49.85"
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls -d1 !(@(${newestTestFolder}|!(test*)))
test1
test2.1
test4.95.89
```

This shows that

```
$ rm -r !(@(${newestTestFolder}|!(test*)))
```

does what you want in a single command all within Bash (with `extglob` enabled) - no extra process invocations (well, `rm`).

The pattern is explained in the Bash manual and means

- `!()` - *not* the pattern within
- `@()` - *one* of the patterns within
- `|` - separates patterns

Comment: nice. but i guess it involves setting newest folder name manually? and you have deleted only the newest one instead of leaving only this one - but this is of course a detail..

Comment: @mnmnc: Yes, this does not look at timestamps at all. The question said that the name was available in a variable. No, I'm deleting the old `test*` directories with this command. The same directories that are shown with the last `ls` command in the first section are the ones that should be deleted with the later shown `rm` command.

Comment: When running `ls -d1 !(@(${newestTestFolder}|!(test*)))` I get `-bash: !: event not found` I tried escaping with \ but then i get unexpected token (

Comment: @yellavon: Did you enable `extglob` as shown? Issue `shopt -s extglob`. For that matter - are you using Bash? Otherwise it will _not_ work :-)

Comment: Yeah, I just needed to enable extglob. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: (I have changed it to grep only the folders that begins with test)

```
for i in `\ls -1 --sort time | grep ^test | tr '\n' ' ' | cut -d " " -f 2-`; 
do 
     rm -r "$i"; 
done
```

yep. Works for me:

```
 ~ > ls
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-08-23 01:08 Dev
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 18:50 latest
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:14 test1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:14 test2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:14 test3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:14 test4
 ~ > for i in `\ls -1 --sort time | grep ^test | tr '\n' ' ' | cut -d " " -f 2-`;
>     do
>          rm -r "$i";
>     done
 ~ > ls
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-08-23 01:08 Dev
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 18:50 latest
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:14 test4
 ~ >
```

The ones that are left is the youngest folder and folder that not matches `test`
My version is universal - you do not need to provide the name of youngest test folder.

And regarding comment below - you can use following line in `for` expression

```
\ls -1 --sort time | grep ^test | tr ' ' '#' | tr '\n' ' ' | cut -d " " -f 2- | tr '#' ' '
```

if you are expecting to have spaces in folder names. I did used `#` as an uncommon character  unlikely to be in folder names. You can use other if you will expect to have either spaces or `#` characters. You can change `#` to combination of characters to limit the risk.

Proof it's working:

```
 ~ > ls
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-08-23 01:08 Dev
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 18:50 latest
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:19 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:19 test1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:19 test2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:19 test3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:20 test 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:20 test5
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:21 test 6
 ~ > for i in `\ls -1 --sort time | grep ^test | tr ' ' '#' | tr '\n' ' ' | cut -d " " -f 2- | tr '#' ' '`;
>     do
>          rm -r "$i";
>     done
 ~ > ls
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-08-23 01:08 Dev
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 18:50 latest
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-08-24 19:21 test 6
 ~ >
```

Comment: This will fail if there are directories with spaces in them. Also, it will not ignore directories named e.g. `latest`, i.e. not _starting_ with `test`.

Comment: @DanielAndersson i've updated my answer. Its foolproof againt spaces in folder names and it will not delete folders like `latest`